# If not, not working

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

So here's my 'if not' part of my code:

```
:open
set/p g=Choice:
if %g%== 1 goto FNVEnd
if %g%== 2 goto KSPEnd
if %g%== 3 goto SKYPEEnd
if not %g%==1|2|3 goto Correct2

:Correct2
cls
echo Welcome.
timeout 3
goto Open
```

Everything is working except the 'if not' part, please help!

Comment: What's wrong? Error? Unexpected output?

Comment: What is expected and what is outputed? @user2650307

Comment: The pipe isn't used as an OR operator in batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that line at all.  If the user did not enter 1, 2, or 3, just fall through to Correct2.

Are you sure the space is ok in the other compares?

You may want to try this:

```
:open
set/p g=Choice:
if "%g%"=="1" goto FNVEnd
if "%g%"=="2" goto KSPEnd
if "%g%"=="3" goto SKYPEEnd

REM If we get here ...
cls
echo Welcome.
timeout 3
goto Open
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying here to check if you got a correct answer, you already did that, falling through will accomplish it.

In the case you did need to IF THIS == THAT OR THAT == THIS...
you will have to use IF, ELSE.

```
REM  ::  AND
IF A==A IF B==B GOTO bothtrue

REM  ::  OR
IF A==A (
  GOTO oneorother
) ELSE (
  IF B==B GOTO oneorother
)

:bothtrue
 ECHO Both were true.
GOTO EOF
:oneorother
 ECHO AT least one was true.
```