# Calling variables do not work, what to do?

Tags: variables, batch-file, call

Hey StackOverflow Community,

I am currently programming my own life simulator called "XinsLife". Currently I want to call a variable that I set before. But it just doesn't work. I tried everything on YouTube and SS64 and could not find what the error was. So I thought I'd ask on StackOverflow. I know this problem is basic and probably everyone can do this, but I am very new to Batch.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am currently at country choosing, so when I choose a country it has to do a variable of what I chose, then goto :savesettings, and display the country that I chose. But it does not work.

C o d e :

```
:countrychoosing
cls
title New Life -- Country choosing
echo.
echo Choose your country:
call :echo-align center "United States"
call :echo-align center "United Kingdom"
call :echo-align center "China"
call :echo-align center "India"
call :echo-align center "More countries to come soon!"
set /p choosecountry=
if "%choosecountry%" equ 1 (
    set chosecountry = United States
    goto savesettings
)

if "%choosecountry%" equ 2 (
    set chosecountry = United Kingdom
    goto savesettings
)   

if "%choosecountry%" equ 3 (
    set chosecountry = China
    goto savesettings
)

if "%choosecountry%" equ 4 (
    set chosecountry = India
    goto savesettings
)

:savesettings
call %chosecountry%
echo You chose the country "%chosecountry%". Do you want to create a save file?
choice /C:YN
if "%errorlevel%" equ 255 goto savesettings
if "%errorlevel%" equ N goto continuetest
if "%errorlevel%" equ Y goto createsavefiletest
if "%errorlevel%" equ 0 goto savesettings
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18046623/2128947 (random selection from responses to this weekly question) - but why use `set/p` when you are also using `choice` (preferred option) to do the same kind of thing?

Comment: Doesn't work. I pressed 1, which should be United States, but it says:

"India" isn't recognized as a command.
You chose the country: "India"

Comment: You don't see a label `echo-align` because I haven't showed you the rest of the code. `echo-align` works perfectly. Its just to align text to the center.

Comment: Oh, and also, the "Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?" thing. Did not help. It still says "India" isn't recognized as a command. You chose the country: "India".

Comment: You need to match this syntax: ```If "%choosecountry%" == "1" (```, and: ```Set "chosecountry=United States"```

Comment: I know you were given a lot of links, but you actually _do_ need to re-read https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564 because you're setting your variables incorrectly.

Comment: Hi Compo, its like I am at the start again. It said exactly the thing that it said at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Why you should use "choice", not "set /p" to accept user-input.

When you use `set /p "var=Some user prompt"` then `var` is set to the string entered from the keyboard.

- But note that if the user's response is simply <kbd>Enter</kbd> then `var` will remain **unchanged**

All fine in theory, if you can be certain that your users will never enter an unexpected string.

Suppose the user enters `2` to your first prompt

The `if` statement would be interpreted as `if "2" equ 2 (`

Since `"2"` and `2` are different, the `if` statement will be evaluated as *false*. You need `if "%choosecountry%" equ "2" (`

So the code now becomes `if "%choosecountry%" equ "2" (`

Suppose the user enters `United Kingdom` to your first prompt, instead of the expected `2`.

The `if` statement would be interpreted as `if "United Kingdom" equ "2" (` - well, that could be fixed with some more code.

But suppose the user enters `UK` -yes. More code...

Suppose the entry was `x"y`. This would lead to a syntax error - and there are oodles of other examples like `%hello` which the user could enter but batch would object to.

Well - most, but probably not all of these unexpected input strings could probably be massaged to allow the `cmd` processor to handle them smoothly, but that's a lot of unnecessary work and code.

The better solution is to use `choice` which you use (but incorrectly, sorry) later in your code.

If you enter `choice /?` from the prompt, you get a full description of `choice`. In summary, you can use the command `choice /C:YN` where `YN` can be any string of unique *alphamerics* - a to z or a digit.

`choice` waits for a single character and will *beep* if one of the choices set by the `/c:` is not used.

If one of the allowed options is used, then it sets the *magic variable* `errorlevel` to a value that depends on the position of the character within the allowed string, so pressing `N` in response to `choice /C:YN` would set `errorlevel` to 2; for `choice /C:NY` to `1`; for `choice /C:ORANGES` to `4`.

*magic variables* are those that are set automatically like `DATE`, `TIME`, `RANDOM` and others. These variables should not be set as part of a program as the value `set` into the variable then overrides the value that the system sets.

*magic variables* otherwise work identically to normal user-variables, and **ALL VARIABLES** are **strings**. If the string is purely numeric then the `set /a` command can be used to perform some mathematical operations. (there are some esoteric exceptions to the `pure`-numeric string requirement - see `set /?` from the prompt for details)

So, to structure a `choice` for use from a menu, you might have

```
choice /C:YN
if "%errorlevel%" equ "255" goto savesettings
if "%errorlevel%" equ "2"   goto continuetest
if "%errorlevel%" equ "1"   goto createsavefiletest
```

Note that each side of the `if` operator ("equ") must be quoted.

OR - you may have

```
choice /C:YN
if errorlevel 255 goto savesettings
if errorlevel 2   goto continuetest
if errorlevel 1   goto createsavefiletest
```

Note that these tests *must* be performed in reverse-numerical order as the meaning of `if errorlevel n` is "if errorlevel is n **or greater than n**"

You could even use

```
choice /C:YN
goto point%errorlevel%
```

where `:point1` is located at `:createsavefiletest`, `:point2` at `:continuetest` and `:point255` at `:savesettings`.

Note that a label is simply a location in a file, so

```
some code...
:xyz
:abc
:hyg
some more code...
```

would mean that `goto xyz`,`goto abc` and`goto hyg` all do exectly the same thing.

This should enable you to solve your problem.

Batch is sensitive to spaces in an ordinary string `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N".  Remove <kbd>Space</kbd> from **both** sides of the `=`.

Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign `"` or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax `set var="value"` is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer, though it did not work. The "India" is not a recognized command was fixed by your comment, but it still says You chose "". @Magoo

Comment: In all probability because you haven't fixed your `set` syntax. I've added the `set` sermons.

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but its again saying "India" is not a recognized command.

EDIT: Now I know, why it didn't work. I used the command call %chosecountry% which is the same result as if I would type into the command prompt "India", I just removed it and now it works. Thanks a lot Magoo.